# Where did my Professor GO?

Tags: cipher, story

You wake up on Monday, realizing you're late to meet with your professor. You put on your hat and hurry down the stairs. Just as you're about to leave, your mom gives you an earful (unfortunately, you still live at home):

> Mom: Don't you have to be somewhere right now? 
> You: Even if I did have
>   to be somewhere, is that any of your business?  
> Mom: Excuse you. Is
>   that tone appropriate?

Without saying another word, you slam the door behind you and leave in a huff. You can't wait to get out of this house.

You open the door of your professor's lab, but he's nowhere to be seen. You poke around for some hints or clues, and discover a small piece of paper with some numbers scrawled on it:

> 052133125073 002034 018102110114103078

Some Monday this is...

**What does this all mean? Is my professor trying to tell me something?**

Comment: I was really confused about why you included the details about still living at home with my parents... But now that I've seen the answer, I'm kicking myself for not seeing what a perfect hint it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to take a walk in the woods. The Prof wants to

> Meet in Pewter.

This is based on

> Pokemon, 3-digit codes corresponding to gen 1 pokemon first letters.
> Meowth Eevee Electabuzz Tentacruel
> Ivysaur Nidoking
> Pidgeot Exeggcute Weezing Tangela Exeggutor Rapidash

Comment: And here I was thinking I didn't drop enough hints. Either way, nice answer!